# SQL insert string from one column into another in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, substring

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

```
   Date          Object_ID           Category   Direction

0  2011-02-02    0H 1234 JKL/987        A          N
1  2011-02-02    0H 4321 BNM/987        A          N
2  2011-02-02    0H 5678+ JKL/987       A          N
3  2011-02-02    0H 8765 BNM/987        A          S
4  2011-02-02    0H 9021+ JKL/987       A          S
5  2011-02-02    0H 1102+ JKL/987       A          N
```

I want to be able to add the string value in the 'Direction' column (either 'N' or 'S') to the 'Object_ID' column at a specific position so that the output of the select statement returns this:

```
   Date          Object_ID           Category   Direction

0  2011-02-02    0H 1234 NJKL/987       A          N
1  2011-02-02    0H 4321 NBNM/987       A          N
2  2011-02-02    0H 5678+NJKL/987       A          N
3  2011-02-02    0H 8765 SBNM/987       A          S
4  2011-02-02    0H 9021+SJKL/987       A          S
5  2011-02-02    0H 1102+NJKL/987       A          N
```

I know that the spacing is odd but it's important that it is maintained. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the reverse of this problem is easier (already having the directional indicator and getting rid of it instead of adding it) I would definitely accept those solutions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example, where data are exactly in 2 different formats based on something in the 8th position, then you can use a case expression with concat().

---

```
with my_data as (
  select '2011-02-02' as date, '0H 1234 JKL/987' as object_id, 'A' as category, 'N' as direction union all
  select '2011-02-02', '0H 4321 BNM/987', 'A', 'N' union all
  select '2011-02-02', '0H 5678+ JKL/987', 'A', 'N' union all
  select '2011-02-02', '0H 8765 BNM/987', 'A', 'S' union all
  select '2011-02-02', '0H 9021+ JKL/987', 'A', 'S' union all
  select '2011-02-02', '0H 1102+ JKL/987', 'A', 'N')
select date, object_id as orig_obj_id, 
 case 
  when substring(object_id, 8, 1) = ' ' 
    then concat(substring(object_id, 1, 8), direction, substring(object_id, 9, 8))
    else concat(substring(object_id, 1, 8), direction, substring(object_id, 10, 7))
  end as mod_obj_id, 
 category, direction
from my_data;
```

| date | orig_obj_id | mod_obj_id | category | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 1234 JKL/987 | 0H 1234 NJKL/987 | A | N |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 4321 BNM/987 | 0H 4321 NBNM/987 | A | N |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 5678+ JKL/987 | 0H 5678+NJKL/987 | A | N |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 8765 BNM/987 | 0H 8765 SBNM/987 | A | S |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 9021+ JKL/987 | 0H 9021+SJKL/987 | A | S |
| 2011-02-02 | 0H 1102+ JKL/987 | 0H 1102+NJKL/987 | A | N |

---

Output easier seen as text vs table above:

```
mod_obj_id
0H 1234 NJKL/987
0H 4321 NBNM/987
0H 5678+NJKL/987
0H 8765 SBNM/987
0H 9021+SJKL/987
0H 1102+NJKL/987
```

Comment: Looks like it's outputting '0H 1234 N JKL/987' instead of '0H 1234 NJKL/987' for the IDs without a '+'

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the code above. The output was copied/pasted. If you're seeing otherwise, then your data is different than what you put in the question.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. There is an extra space between the 1234 and JKL/987 that I did not put in the original question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If your data indeed has 2 spaces for some, then you'll need to adjust this code. You can replace two spaces with one as part of the process, but really depends on your data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `regexp_replace`:

```
select t.rnum, t.date, regexp_replace(t.object_id, '(?<=\d)\+*\s(?=[A-Z])', 
     case when regexp_substr(t.object_id, '(?<=\d)\+*\s(?=[A-Z])') = ' ' 
          then '  '||t.direction else '+'||t.direction end), 
     t.category, t.direction 
from tbl t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A4GXc8fx).